# How to animate background property in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, background, jquery-animate, sprite

I'm using CSS sprites via background property and I can't animate it in jQuery.

Is there a way or equivalent method how to achieve this?

```
$(function(){
    $(".webdesign").mouseover(function(){
        $(".webdesign").animate({
        background: "url("../images/category-hover.png") 0 0"
        });
    });
});
```

I'm animating url property and position.

Comment: Which property are you animating? The `url()` of the image or the position?

Comment: I'm animating url property and position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't animate an url property, but sure you can animate the background position like this:

```
$("body").animate({"background-position-y": "200px"}, "slow");
```

[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkzNM/)

If you also want a transition to another image, I'd suggest you to use 2 divs with 100% size and position: absolute, so you can animate their left: and top: properties, and also to animate their opacity to blend over to another image.